# Main menu entries created with Alacarte - No icons in dock

Tags: gnome, gui, dock, alacarte

I created several main menu entries with Alacarte. I added an icon and I can perfectly see the icon in my application overview. When I open the application, I cannot see the application icon in the dock and also the context menu after a click does not show "New Windows" and "Add to Favorites".

This is an example for a entry created by Alacarte:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Radix Wallet
Exec=/home/martin/.Software/Radix-Wallet-1.2.5.AppImage
Comment=
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/martin/.Software/Radix-DLT-logo.jpg
Type=Application
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Application in the search]

[image: Missing icon in the dock]

Comment: Should be good at first sigh. However, try converting the icon file to .png instead. The icon being in jpeg could be the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, converting the file to .png did not help. Is there something like a maximal filesize?

Comment: There will indeed be something like a maximal file size. It can be related to a wmclass confusion. Adding the correct wmclass to the launcher would solve the issue.I tried to find the ApppImage to see for myself, but I could not locate it. On Flathub, reference is made to the github site where I do not see any AppImage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the correct `wmclass` in the `.desktop` launcher.

Launch the application. Then determine the window class by running `xprop | grep WM_CLASS`. This returns something like

WM_CLASS(STRING) = "", ""

Add a line to your `.desktop launcher that specifies its class name as:

```
StartupWMClass=<Class Name>
```

where `<Class Name>` should be replaced by the actual output of `xprop`.